# How get JSON data from inside a function and display it on textfield in swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, function, api

I have been learning how to parse json data into swift...i am trying to show area of my pincode from into a textfield...i have created two three swift files mapview.swift, maphandler.swift and mapmodel.swift.the problem is i want to get the data from inside the function to another swift file so that i can display it on a textfield...i have  tried creating a struct to store that pin code and then pass it on to the mapview.swift but no luck

This is the code which is able to get pincode as data

```
func parseJson(Json:Data) {

    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do{
        let decodedData = try decoder.decode(MapModel.self, from: Json)
        let format = decodedData.results[0].formatted_address
        var pinCode:String!
        for item in decodedData.results[0].address_components{
            if item.types[0] == "postal_code"{
                pinCode =  ( item.long_name)

            }
        }

       print(pinCode)


    }
    catch{

        print(error)
        return 

    }


}
```

All i want to do is get that pincode data to mapview.swift so that i can display it on a textfield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like what you want is your function to return the pin code. You can do that as follows:

```
func parsePinCode(fromJson json: Data) -> String? {

    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do {
        let decodedData = try decoder.decode(MapModel.self, from: json)
        let format = decodedData.results[0].formatted_address
        var pinCode:String!
        for item in decodedData.results[0].address_components{
            if item.types[0] == "postal_code"{
                pinCode = (item.long_name)

                // Return the pinCode if we found one
                return pinCode
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    return nil
}
```

You can use this function by calling it from other swift files as follows (where `myJsonData` is the json data you want to decode):

```
let pinCode = parsePinCode(fromJson: myJsonData)
```

EDIT:

If you want to return multiple values, you could create a struct with all the values you want to return. For example:

```
struct MapData {
    var pinCode: String?
    var address: String?
}

func parsePinCode(fromJson json: Data) -> MapData? {

    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do {
        let decodedData = try decoder.decode(MapModel.self, from: json)

        var mapData = MapData()

        mapData.address = decodedData.results[0].formatted_address

        for item in decodedData.results[0].address_components {
            if item.types[0] == "postal_code" {
                mapData.pinCode = (item.long_name)
                break
            }
        }

        return mapData
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: And what if i had two data in that function that needed to be retieved??

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how you could have multiple values returned from the function by using a struct.

Comment: In second case i am storing the values in the struct am i correct??

Comment: Cannot access it buddy...do i have any other options so that i can access it